# Using Python 3, my JSON file is only saving the most recent entries. How can I get it to capture all data?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I've made a super simple social media tracking program, so that after every time I use Twitter I can log the amount of time I spent there (for personal accountability), and then get a sum of my total time for that day.

I'm writing to a JSON file to ensure data persistence each time I open and close the program, and it's mostly working great.... except that it only stores the EIGHT most recent entries to the dictionary.

Here's my code. Works great except only remembering the most recent eight entries.

````
import json

with open("social_media_log.json", "r") as read_file:
 logged_times = json.load(read_file)
with open("social_media_log_DAYS.json", "r") as read_file:
 days = json.load(read_file)

from datetime import date
today = date.today()
print(today)
number = 0

def ask():
 print("What would you like to do?")
 print("L = LOG social media time")
 print("R = get a REPORT of usage")
 print("E = EXIT program")

 response = input()
    
 if response == "l":
  log()
 elif response == "r":
  report()
 elif response == "e":
  return
 else:
  ask() 
    

def log():
 global number
 logged_times
 days
 number += 1
 print("how long did you use social media just now? # of seconds")
 entry = input() 
 logged_times[number] = {"date" : str(today), "amount" : entry}
 if str(today) in days:
  pass
 else:
  days.append(str(today))
 print(logged_times)
 print(days)
 amounts = []
 for i in logged_times:
  amounts.append(int(logged_times[i]['amount']))
 print(amounts)
 print("total time is ", sum(amounts))
 with open("social_media_log.json", "w") as write_file:
  json.dump(logged_times, write_file)
 with open("social_media_log_DAYS.json", "w") as write_file:
  json.dump(days, write_file) 
 ask()```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code requires the two JSON files to already be present, could you include their contents in your question?

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome!! 


Here's the contents of the first JSON file ("social_media_log.json") (the amounts are totally made-up for testing purposes): 


`{'1': {'date': '2023-02-27', 'amount': 57}, '2': {'date': '2023-02-27', 'amount': '57557'}, '3': {'date': '2023-02-27', 'amount': '79'}, '4': {'date': '2023-02-27', 'amount': '9'}, '5': {'date': '2023-02-27', 'amount': '123'}, '6': {'date': '2023-02-27', 'amount': '234'}, '7': {'date': '2023-02-27', 'amount': '5759'}} `


And the second ("social_media_log_DAYS.json") is just: 

`{'2023-02-27'} `

Comment: @Jasmijn I solved my own problem! The issue was, I was resetting the count every time I ran the program - 
`number = 0`
Once I updated that to 
`number = len(logged_times)`
the JSON file continues to expand each time I add new entries, while retaining previous ones. Thanks for your help tho!!

Comment: @SamJ.Miller You can answer your own question if you like.  There is a delay in doing so but it is perfectly acceptable.  Alternately if you don't think someone would have this problem in the future you could delete this question. Finally thanks for showing us your code and the data. In the future I would recommend you put the data in the question via an edit as data in comments is hard to read.